# create a column that can count the fraction

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe similar to below:

```
name  x     y
Sam   1     NA
John  1     NA
Lilly 0      1
Lilly 1      1
John  NA     0
Sam   1      NA
```

From this dataframe, I am hoping to create two new column called percentage_0 and percentage_1

For each name, I calculate the percentage of 1 and percentage of 0. For example. Lilly has a total 4 values 0, 1, 1, 1, the return should be percentage_0: 0.25   and percentage 1: 0.75

The final return should look like this

```
name  percentage_0   percentage 1
Sam    0              1
John   0.5            0.5
lilly  0.25           0.75
```

my code is

```
df['percentage_0'] = df[df['x'] == 1].count()/len(df['name'])
```

but this code doesn't work

Answer (score 2):

Try with `melt` and `crosstab`:

```
s=df.melt('name').dropna()
out = (pd.crosstab(s['name'], s['value'], normalize='index')
         .add_prefix('percentage_')
      )
```

Output:

```
value  percentage_0.0  percentage_1.0
name                                 
John             0.50            0.50
Lilly            0.25            0.75
Sam              0.00            1.00
```

---

**Update**: `melt` can be slow, try with groupby:

```
groups = df.groupby('name')
out = (groups['x'].value_counts().rename_axis(index=('name',None))
   .add(groups['y'].value_counts().rename_axis(index=('name',None)), fill_value=0)
   .unstack(fill_value=0)
)

out.div(out.sum(1), axis=0)
```

Comment: could you tell me how to deal with 'value'? I have two value columns, one is 'x' and one is 'y'.

Comment: Is there any faster way to run this. the data size is large and it took forever to run

Comment: Does your data have other columns? It shouldn't be that slow with just 3 columns.

Comment: No other column, just those three, but it has 206605310 rows. I ran it for 6 minutes and still no result

Comment: @totolow see if the updated answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `NA` is some form of `np.nan` (which would be good to standardize anyways):

```py
df.set_index("name", inplace=True)

df = df.stack().reset_index(drop=True, level=1).reset_index()

df = (
    df.groupby("name")[0]
    .value_counts(normalize=True)
    .unstack(level=1)
    .fillna(0)
    )

df.columns = map(lambda x: f"percentage_{int(x)}", df.columns)
```

Returns:

```py
       percentage_0  percentage_1
name
John           0.50          0.50
Lilly          0.25          0.75
Sam            0.00          1.00
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's construct the dataframe in the question firstly:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
name = ['Sam', 'John', 'Lilly', 'Lilly', 'John', 'Sam']
x = [1, 1, 0, 1, np.nan, 1]
y = [np.nan, np.nan, 1, 1, 0, np.nan]
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':name, 'x':x, 'y':y})
df
```

Get the dataframe in the question as follows:

[image]

Now let's get the dataframe you want, in order to get the count of 0 and 1 fastly, we had better convert it into numpy array with the function "values":

```
d = {'name':list(set(df['name'])), 'percentage_0':[], 'percentage_1':[]}
for e in d['name']:
    value = df[df['name'] == e].values
    value1 = np.count_nonzero(value == 1)
    value0 = np.count_nonzero(value == 0)
    d['percentage_0'].append(value0/(value0+value1))
    d['percentage_1'].append(value1/(value0+value1))
pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Finally we will get the dataframe you want:
[image]